# While retweeting via abraham OAuth API My application restricted from Twitter

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm using this code:

```
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$oauth_token,$oauth_token_secret); 
$tweet->setProxy(['CURLOPT_PROXY' => $rand_ip,
'CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD' => $rand_ip_auth,
'CURLOPT_PROXYPORT' => $rand_ip_port,
]); 
$tweet->setTimeouts(25, 120);
$response = $tweet->post("statuses/retweet/$tweet_id");
sleep(12); //for 12 seconds sleep so that twitter rate limit not hit.
```

Even also I'm using random proxies for every request, but still my Twitter application is restricted.

Please help me that I could retweet without hitting the rate limit.

Comment: I believe the API has limits based on the user you're requesting as well as your app user. Using a proxy won't help with those. See [Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits).